# Creating multithreads continuously

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

I have a string list includes file paths. The count of list elements is 80. I want to create 8 threads continuously until files in list have moved. If a thread finishes its work, I will create one thread so that thread count must be 8.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: please share with us what you've tried thus far and please be more specific: what do you need help with? PS: why would you want to replace finished threads with a new dummy one / why does thread count have to be 8?

Answer (score 1):

Unless each thread is writing to a different drive, having multiple threads copying files is *slower* than doing it with a single thread. The disk drive can only do one thing at a time. If you have eight threads all trying to write to the same disk drive, then it takes extra time to do disk head seeks and such.

Also, if you don't have at least eight CPU cores, then trying to run eight concurrent threads is going to require extra thread context switches. If you're doing this on a four-core machine, then you shouldn't have more than four threads working on it.

If you really need to have eight threads doing this, then put all of the file paths into a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx), start eight threads, and have them go to work. So you have eight persistent threads rather than starting and stopping threads all the time. Something like this:

```
BlockingCollection<string> filePaths = new BlockingCollection<string>();
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

// add paths to queue
foreach (var path in ListOfFilePaths)
    filePaths.Add(path);
filePaths.CompleteAdding();

// start threads to process the paths
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(CopyFiles);
    threads.Add(t);
    t.Start();
}

// threads are working. At some point you'll need to clean up:
foreach (var t in threads)
{
    t.Join();
}
```

Your `CopyFiles` method looks like this:

```
void CopyFiles()
{
    foreach (var path in filePaths.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        CopyTheFile(path);
    }
}
```

Since you're working with .NET 4.0, you could use `Task` instead of `Thread`. The code would be substantially similar.

Comment: I want to restrict the threadcount with 8 because we have 8 CPU cores. When some threads finish their work I must be calculate the thread count which is working now. The count is smaller than 8, I must be create threads as the 8-count. How can I do this?

Comment: @user3894737: My answer shows you how to make sure that 8 threads are working and will continue working until the input (the list of file paths) is exhausted.